# JIRA as a subdomain without port. htaccess or virtualhost

Tags: apache, jira, cpanel

Ok. I have a dedicated box running centOS 5, it has cPanel installed to make things a bit easier I also have JIRA and SVN setup and running. So with that said I am trying to have a subdomain eg. jira.domain.com but, not sure how to set it up, cpanel doesn't appear to store the virtualhosts in the typical local `/etc/httpd/conf.d/....` so I am wondering how would I set up jira as a subdomain for JIRA where I dont have to have the port displaying as well.

Would I use htaccess for this or add a virtualhost somehow or what? If I have to add a virtualhost, how will that effect my other subdomains, if the virtualhost is added to the right spot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you can archive it is to make a subdomain and add a virtual host mapping to Apache.

Here is my default configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName jira.domain.com

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyRequests       Off
    ProxyPreserveHost   On

    ProxyPass           /    http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse    /    http://localhost:8080/

    ErrorLog            /var/log/apache2/jira.error.log
    CustomLog           /var/log/apache2/jira.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

In order for this to work you need to activate

1. VirtualHost configuration
2. Proxy Module: mod_proxy

Comment: change __default__:80 to *:80

Answer (score 1):

Just a note.

You'll need to enable these apache2 moduels:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
```